# Pattern name/Convention -> Class that merge different attributes from other classes

Tags: properties, merge, design-patterns, convention

I wanted to know if there is a known pattern or convention for the following scenario:

I have two classes: MAT (name:String, address:String) & MATversion(type:String, version:int)

Now I have a DataGrid (DataTable) which will take a generic List of objects for the column mapping and data filling.

The columns should be name, type, version. (Which are distributed in MAT and MATversion)

So I create a class to make this work. This class will merge the needed properties from each class (MAT, MATversion).

-> MAT_MATversion (name:String, type:String, version:int).

Does there exist a naming convention for such an class like MAT_MATversion? Any pattern that mirrors that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why the merged result has to be a unique class?

I'm assuming every MAT object has a single MATversion
you can add a couple of custom properties who will return the type and version of the underlying MATversion object
In C# this would result in something like this

```
public class MAT{
  public String name{ get;set;};
  public String adress{ get;set;};
  public MATversion myVersion;
  public String type {
    get{
      return myVersion.type;
    }
    set{
      myVersion.type = value;
    }
  }
  public int version {
    get{
      return myVersion.version;
    }
    set{
      myVersion.version = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm aware that this doesn't answer the question about design patterns, but I couldn't ask/suggest another approach in a comment since I don't have that right yet.

Comment: The problem is, that I get my MAT object from a webservice and my MATversion object from another webservice!

Comment: So you first get your MAt object from webservice A, and then based on that you go and ask your MATVersion object from Webservice B? When you get the answer of webservice B you can then add it to the MAT object with myMATobject.myVersion = myMATversionobject; Where myMATversionobject is the object you just received from the webservice. (I edited my example to make this possible: private=>public)